# Istio Service Entry Not Working

Tags: istio

**What Version of Istio and Kubernetes are you using, where did you get Istio from, Installation details**

```
istioctl version
Version: 0.8.0
GitRevision: 6f9f420f0c7119ff4fa6a1966a6f6d89b1b4db84
User: root@48d5ddfd72da
Hub: docker.io/istio
GolangVersion: go1.10.1
BuildStatus: Clean


kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"9", GitVersion:"v1.9.7", GitCommit:"dd5e1a2978fd0b97d9b78e1564398aeea7e7fe92", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-04-19T00:05:56Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"9", GitVersion:"v1.9.1", GitCommit:"3a1c9449a956b6026f075fa3134ff92f7d55f812", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-01-04T11:40:06Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.2", Compiler
```

**Is Istio Auth enabled or not ?**
Auth is not enabled, I used istio-demo.yaml to install istio

**What happened**:
I tried to use the external example (ServiceEntry):

```
cat <<EOF | istioctl create -f -
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  name: httpbin-ext
spec:
  hosts:
  - httpbin.org
  ports:
  - number: 80
    name: http
    protocol: HTTP
EOF

cat <<EOF | istioctl create -f -
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  name: google-ext
spec:
  hosts:
  - www.google.com
  ports:
  - number: 443
    name: https
    protocol: HTTPS
EOF
```

**I keep getting errors when I try to curl from the sleep pod:**

```
root@sleep-6ccf857cc6-b9jh4:/#  curl http://httpbin.org/headers -I
HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable
content-length: 19
content-type: text/plain
date: Thu, 14 Jun 2018 10:40:20 GMT
server: envoy

root@sleep-6ccf857cc6-b9jh4:/# curl -I https://www.google.com
curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to www.google.com:443
```

**Some log output from the istio proxy sidecar of the sleep pod:**

```
[2018-06-14 11:00:39.419][14][info][upstream] external/envoy/source/server/lds_api.cc:60] lds: add/update listener 'tcp_0.0.0.0_443'
[2018-06-14T11:00:37.373Z] "HEAD /headers HTTP/1.1" 503 UH 0 19 0 - "-" "curl/7.35.0" "d06828ed-7fd6-9383-adad-170177b00427" "httpbin.org" "-"
[2018-06-14 11:01:40.298][14][info][upstream] external/envoy/source/common/upstream/cluster_manager_impl.cc:388] add/update cluster out.www.google.com|https starting warming
[2018-06-14 11:01:40.299][14][info][upstream] external/envoy/source/common/upstream/cluster_manager_impl.cc:395] warming cluster out.www.google.com|https complete
```

Comment: Are you using Istio inside o a Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE) cluster?
If so, I found this tutorial that might be useful: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/installing-istio

Answer (score 1):

Am running this on AWS, but was able to fix this with help from the istio/github/issues page...

Had to add RESOLUTION: DNS to the serviceentry

```
cat <<EOF | istioctl create -f -
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  name: httpbin-ext
spec:
  hosts:
  - httpbin.org
  ports:
  - number: 80
    name: http
    protocol: HTTP
  resolution: DNS
EOF

cat <<EOF | istioctl create -f -
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  name: google-ext
spec:
  hosts:
  - www.google.com
  ports:
  - number: 443
    name: https
    protocol: HTTPS
  resolution: DNS
EOF
```

Link is:

https://github.com/istio/old_issues_repo/issues/392